# Transfering already installed steam games onto another drive

Tags: steam

Ok so I've seen the other questions about installing games onto another drive(SSD) and I've already done that properly for any new game that I have been getting.

However I want to know if there is a proper way to transfer games from my old drive over to the new drive without having to uninstall and then re-download them.

I already tried copying the folders over but all that does is make steam not know where the games are anymore and I'm not sure how to change the location that it looks for a particular game once it is already installed on my C drive.

Thank you!

Comment: There are a few questions on this topic already, but the answer I'd suggest is actually not a direct duplicate.  You can [check it out over here.](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1580/is-it-possible-to-install-steam-games-to-two-different-locations/16467#16467)  I use SteamMover and it's spartan, but works fine.

Comment: I just needed clarification on the steps and the other question's top answer seems to be what I needed. Thanks and sorry about the duplicate I didn't search enough.